# Geo-coordinates provider for European cities and districts

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm looking for database with geo-data about city districts for all cities of the Europe.
I have plans to use it in my google-maps based appication.

For example, if you try to search with query "Paris, Paris 11" at Google Maps, you will see the highlighted area of Paris-11 district.

[image: sample map]

I've already found great database with country regions polygone: https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=420419

Can anybody help me with same database for city regions?

Or maybe google maps api has some method to receive polygonal coordinates of selected city district?

PS all national earth data-tables are stored here: https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=394713